# override really easy field validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, prototype

I use really-easy-field-validation for prototype plugin.

In my form I have 2 buttons, and I need to validate only when "Send" button is hit, but when the 2nd button - "Save" is hit, I want the form to be submitted but with NO validation.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes to the same problem, here is the workarount that I had used.

I used jquery in the following way, when pressing the button that I did not want validation to happen, I changed all the classes names from 'required' or 'validate-number' to 'overrideValidation'. I saved each class name in the $.data powerful object. By that, the plugin didn't have nothing to validate since it relies on these names.

When pressing the other button, I took all the clesses names from the $.data object and put them back.

Hope it will help some of you.